# Did Varda help Frodo and Sam on the Quest to Mordor?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

When Frodo speaks the words to light up the light of Eärendil it seemed strange that he knew exactly what to say even though he had never used the phial before, and then Frodo and Sam see a star in Mordor where it is a barren wasteland.

I think Varda made a star visible to them for hope. Did she help Frodo and Sam?

Comment: Vile? Aw come on, the Phial of Galadriel aint that bad.

Comment: hahahaha sorry about that

Comment: [Related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71554/why-does-frodo-cry-o-elbereth-gilthoniel-at-weathertop)

Comment: I've heard nothing to suggest that Varda played a part in the Quest of Mount Doom, but the question linked below shows that Eru himself did play a part: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/when-did-eru-interfere-in-arda-directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Frodo is shown to know some measure of the language of the Elves, when Samwise takes it in the chapter "The Choices of Master Samwise" -

"and then his tongue was loosed and his voice cried in a language which he did not know:
  A Elbereth Gilthoniel etc...."

So - it seems that the Phial of Galadriel bestows upon the user some measure of extra ability.

The implication seems to be that the star Sam sees in Mordor is the Silmaril of Earendil

Comment: wait! so Frodo and Sam actually saw Earendil the mariner?!

Comment: But Frodo for lack of a better word invoked the name Elbereth at Weathertop in the first book

Comment: that is true - Frodo does seem to be aware of Elbereth as upon he and Sam meeting the elves on the road, he hears them singing and says "they spoke the name of Elbereth!" 
Later in that same meeting, Gildor says to Frodo: "may Elbereth protect you!"

So - when Frodo is beset by the wraiths, it is not unlikely that he would call upon Elbereth - the Middle Earth equivalent of someone shouting 'Oh my God!' when in distress lol

Comment: Would it not be too out of the question aswell that Bilbo may have passed on stories and knowledge of Elven lore to Frodo following the time he spent with him in Bag End? Bilbo spent some time in Rivendell during the Quest of Erebor, so likely he learned some knowledge there. He was held in contempt by other hobbits for his "eccentricity" after his first adventure, but Frodo we know loved him and saw him as a father figure for much of his life. Frodo had 17 odd years after Bilbo left and acquiring the ring to read Bilbo's adventures. I'd say he knew more than was let on in the LotR books.